# Threejs webGL renderer - multiple scene data is not available in toDataURL

Tags: three.js, pdf-generation, renderer, todataurl

We use three.js to render multiple scenes listed in the order one by one (using setScissorTest(true)) in an Angular app. Currently, I am trying to export the rendered scenes into a PDF using JSPDF. The `renderer.domElement.toDataURL` is used to export the renderer content into a JPEG stream, which will be added into the PDF.

The contents which are visible on the screen is getting exported into the PDF. But the scenes on the page which can be viewed by scroll down is not available in the dataURL stream. So the resulting PDF misses the objects which are not visible on the screen.

Example -
https://plnkr.co/edit/Ty8BZaDcflCJH5tH  (chrome)

I tried approaches like -

1. Exporting each scene into an image by using a separate webGLRenderer for PDF generation (without scissors test enabled)
2. Using a hidden canvas for PDF export.

But I am facing issues with the above approaches, is there any way to export multiple scenes of a three.js webGL renderer irrespective of whether the scene is visible in the screen or not?

Thanks in advance,

Satheesh

Comment: Does the export work correctly if you zoom the browser so the canvas fits without scrolling?

Comment: I didn't tried that, but in my case I have three scenes, the first two scenes are default visible and the last one needs to be scrolled down. In normal case when I scroll down and try to generate PDF it works.

Comment: I'm wondering if Chrome isn't rendering the hidden part of the canvas. Exporting with the full canvas visible (even if it's not your normal use-case) will say whether that shot-in-the-dark was a hit or a miss. You _may_ need to render to an off-screen target to capture all of the data for your export.

Comment: If you want to be able to export to PDF then you probably have to put a 2D canvas at each element and draw using `drawImage` like [the solution at bottom of this page](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-multiple-scenes.html). It will be slower than the scissor method but it will allow printing. You will need to skip the `isOffscreen` check at least once for each canvas.

Comment: Thanks gman, TheJim01, 

@gman, I will work with your above idea. Also I don't deal with many objects I can little bit compromise on the performance.

@ TheJim01 - can you explain more on this line - " You may need to render to an off-screen target to capture all of the data for your export " ?